# I have a problem implementing states in my Flex app, please help!

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, states

Hey guys, I'm trying to work out how to use states in my Flex app.

I've created two states, State1 and Stage 2. Both are based off the base state. I've created a few visual elements for State1, and given each of them includeIn="State1".

But when I'm in design mode and click on State2, these elements are still visible? Why is that?

If I try to delete them while State2 is selected, all that happens is RemoveChild is added to the State2 tag. Is this how I'm supposed to do it?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I come in mind is that you added those controls in the base state. 
Try to remove the controls from the base state and try again.